# layer-list drawable not drawn correctly

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, drawable

I am trying to create a simple layer-list drawable for my Android app. When I set the drawable as src of an ImageView it is not drawn correctly:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:top="20dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/dark_gray" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:left="20dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/dark_gray" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Just two ovals with a little offset to each other. Nothing special (just a test) but it does not work.

It seems that `android:left|right|bottom|top` is the problem. If I use only of of these commands the drawable is drawn correctly. If two or more are used the ImageView stays empty.

**Works:**

```
   <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
      <item android:top="20dp">
         <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/dark_gray" />
         </shape>
      </item>

      <item>
         <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/dark_gray" />
         </shape>
      </item>
   </layer-list>
```

**Does NOT work** (like the first example):

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <layer-list xmlns:android="..." >
      <item android:top="20dp" android:left="20dp">
         <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/dark_gray" />
         </shape>
      </item>
   </layer-list>
```

What is wrong here?

**EDIT:** @ Rod_Algonquin
I use a quite simple layout to test the drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#aaa" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_logo"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/testDrawable" >
    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

It seems that the number of `android:left|right|bottom|top` arguments is not the source of the problem but the concrete value being used.

**This drawable works fine and:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:top="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#0f0" />  
        </shape>
    </item> 
</layer-list>
```

**This one does not draw anything** (the ImageView is just transparent):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:top="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#0f0" />  
        </shape>
    </item> 
</layer-list>
```

The only difference here is the value of `android:top`. 1dp does not work. 2dp works without any problem.

Any idea?

Comment: It is perfectly working on mine. maybe its your layout post it

Comment: when you say ImageView stays empty not even a color gray?

Comment: I have updated the question and added the layout I use. Nothing special though. I examinded the problem further and it seems that the values of the android:left|right|bottom|top attributes are using the problem: While `android:top="2dp"`workes fine, the ImageView is blank/transparent when `android:top="1dp"`is being used...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the `layer-list` drawable as an image resource of the ImageView. `android:src` will only accept an image not a drawable thus giving you nothing in there.

**solution:**

Instead of putting it in the `android:src` put it in the `background` where you can freely use the drawable.

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_logo"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/testDrawable" >
</ImageView>
```